# The CPU utilization on my TPU-VM is low and I'm not sure why

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, tpu

I'm running my AutoKeras script on a Google TPU VM (not Colab) and the maximum CPU usage I've seen from it is 15% within the Monitoring tab for TPUs in the Cloud Console. My data is formatted as a Parquet file and there's about 12M datapoints. There's no reported disk usage but it's holding a consistent 28GB of data in memory.

I'm very new to this field but I've followed all the troubleshooting steps listed on the Cloud Platform for low TPU usage. I also tried to preprocess my data and optimize my code as much as possible. It's both concerning for the lackluster usage but also because the model runs better using my laptop's GPU than it does on the TPU.

Any help would be appreciated and I can provide any needed additional info.

Comment: Perhaps your model is not optimized for TPU. Does your plan allow for 100% usage?

Comment: @TimRoberts I got in through the TPU Research Cloud program and the email said "quota free" so I'm assuming I have no limit on it. I'm not sure what else I'd need to do in order to optimize it for TPU usage.

Comment: I would suggest contacting Google Support for optimization questions like this. https://cloud.google.com/contact